# Install PECL mailparse on XAMPP?

Tags: xampp, php, pecl

Similar to [Is it possible to install Mailparse extension via PECL installation - without recompiling PHP](https://serverfault.com/questions/228061/is-it-possible-to-install-mailparse-extension-via-pecl-installation-without-rec) I'm trying to install mailparse on xampp. XAMPP actually has a guide for this, and I've tried to follow along.

http://wiki.cerb4.com/wiki/Installing_on_XAMPP_MacOSX

I've got the latest version (1.7.3)  [via the XAMPP site](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html), and I had the same problems mentioned in the other question until I installed the dev package (oops) but then it did say that it installed and that it modified the php.ini file, and I can confirm that, previously there was no `extension="mailparse.so"` and now it is there.

However, when I check the system using phpinfo() it does not show up, and when I try using the mailparse commands it gives an error, for example

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses()
```

I have already restarted XAMPP, just not sure what to do/check next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide describes installing OAuth. Installing PECL should be very similar.

http://www.sumardi.net/2011/06/04/installing-oauth-extension-in-xampp-for-mac-os-x/

Comment: Linkrot - this answer is now useless.